# Does Gmail (and other mail services) send a pingback/response to the sender, when I hit "Mark spam"?

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, hotmail

We send out email via our own SMTP server. Is there a way to make Gmail (and others) send some kind of pingback or response, if receivers mark our mail as spam?

Is this even a feature provided by Gmail/Hotmail etc?

Comment: Wow, that would be an *awesome* way for you spammers to tell which addresses are real.

Comment: Thanks for the "_you_ spammers" comment... Anyways, the real purpose (or our purpose) would be to improve the quality of mailing lists - remove those who mark mail as spam.

MailChimp etc would probably benefit from this feature as well.

Comment: What a load of traffic this would produce I can't imagine

Answer (score 1):

Email inbox services either accept an email message or reject it completely as spam, often saying so, but I don’t believe that any will provide automatic feedback once the email is delivered to the recipient’s inbox.

There are blacklists that indicate known sources of spam and the better ones are dynamic, continually adding and removing senders from the blacklists. These are high-quality blacklists that I use to filter my incoming email:

- [Spamhaus ZEN](http://www.spamhaus.org/zen/)
- [SpamCop](http://www.spamcop.net/bl.shtml)

You might benefit from periodically checking for your sending IP address on these lists.

Answer (score 1):

No.

- First, a huge privacy violation - "what business of yours is it what I did with an e-mail from you?"
- Second, this would bring huge benefits to spammers (as @Wooble mentions in the comment) - allowing them to judge the effectiveness of spam campaigns, verify which accounts are active, and tune the content to slip through
- Third, most spam received has forged headers, so the "From" address is fake anyway.

However, if you want to track your e-mails, you can

- track click-throughs *from* your e-mails
- request receipt notifications

Answer (score 0):

Hotmail has this feature.
You need to enlist with their "Junk Email Reporting" program.
They send you a note whenever someone clicks "junk" on one of your emails. This way you can unsubscribe them.